# Angular - receiving JSON from Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, angular

Unfortunately, I do not have the intended effect. I would like to devices automatically map to an object based on JSON. What is wrong? Do I have to create angular objects adequate to those working in the spring (same fields, etc.)? I want to be able to display this data in .html.

GET http://localhost:8080/devices gives:

```
   [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "connectionName": "Pracownik1",
    "deviceName": "Samsung J5",
    "historyDays": 7,
    "startConnection": "2018-04-28",
    "actualLocation": {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2018-04-28",
      "time": "13:00:00",
      "gps_longitude": "22,157",
      "gps_latitude": "57,15"
    },
    "historyLocations": [],
    "owner": {
      "id": 1,
      "login": "admin",
      "password": "admin"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "connectionName": "Pracownik2",
    "deviceName": "Samsung galaxy S7",
    "historyDays": 7,
    "startConnection": "2018-04-28",
    "actualLocation": {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2018-04-28",
      "time": "14:00:00",
      "gps_longitude": "22,187",
      "gps_latitude": "58,156"
    },
    "historyLocations": [],
    "owner": {
      "id": 1,
      "login": "admin",
      "password": "admin"
    }
  }
]
```

And I have:

**device.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  devicesURL = 'http://localhost:8080/devices';

  public getDevicesForUser() {
    return  this.http.get(this.devicesURL);
  }
}
```

and

**google-maps.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DeviceService} from '../device.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-maps',
  templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit {

  devices: any;

  lat: number = 52.2158186;
  lng: number = 20.9987672;

  constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceService.getDevicesForUser().
    subscribe(data => {
      this.devices = data;
    });
  }

}
```

**google-maps.component.html**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"> <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker> </agm-map>
```

Comment: add a `.map(res => res.json())` to the end of the `this.http.get(...)`, that should fix it

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: could you share the html code that you use? also, have you tried adding `headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, { 'Accept': 'application/json' })`?

Comment: `<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>`

Comment: It's html code my component

Comment: Yes, I have headers in my device.service.ts

Comment: but you dont appear to have an accept header. could you add the html to the question? do you have an ngFor or anything?

Comment: Sorry, I have header, but don't have accept in header.

Comment: try adding it, that might help you

Comment: I don't have ngFor, but i try show devices in console.log(devices) and see "undefined"

Comment: well you need an ngFor or you wont be able to display all the markers, and your log should be `console.log(this.devices)`

Comment: console.log(this.devices) also show "undefined". I will try add Accept in header.

Comment: I also have a question. I would like add markers for my devices with actual location. In component can I use `device[0].actualLocation.gps_longitude?`

Comment: you can but that will only create 1 marker

Comment: I know. I will write a method to create a more markers. I will use ngFor

Answer (score 1):

Really, I have no idea what do you want to do. Supouse that you want do write some like

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let device of devices" 
     [latitude]="device.actualLocation.gps_latitude" 
     [longitude]="device.actualLocation.gps_longitude">
</agm-marker
```

That's, create a mark each device you have (as the latitude is in the property gps_latitude of the property actualLocation of your object device you must use device.actualLocation.gps_latitude)

Answer (score 0):

I have a 5.27 Angular version. I read that do not have to use .map(res => res.json()) because angular new http automatic conversion from JSON to an object. Unfortunatelly, if I add map(res => res.json()) and import HttpClient, my object devices don't map.

Comment: That's correct. You should not have to map your response. I've added an answer below which should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in Angular 5. You can do it like below:

***Code***

device.ts

```
export interface Device {
  id: number;
  connectionName: string;
  etc .....
}
```

device.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Device } from './device'

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  devicesURL = 'http://localhost:8080/devices';

  public getDevicesForUser: Array<Device> () {
    return  this.http.get<Array<Device>>(this.devicesURL);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you also change add the type to the `get` call?

Comment: Yes, i changed to `this.http.get<Array<Device>>(this.devicesURL);`

Comment: You should also change `devices: any;` in `google-maps.component.ts` to `devices: Array<Device>;`. What is the issue you are getting now?

Comment: Yes, I also changed devices: Array<Device>;

Comment: I have no idea what is the reason this problem.